Snowpark- How to read a from a stage file using snowpark sesssion?
I have multiple file in stage and want to read the contents from it.
For example, i have below file in the stage- single file for this case
from snowfake.snowpark.context import get_active_session

session = get_active_session()

location = "@data_stage/emp_data/file_path/emp.paraquet"

df = session.read.paraquet(location)

df.show()


this file have 3 column name and in the result only it returning the empty row value .
even i tried with below approach
select t.$1 from @mystage (file_format => 'myformat', pattern => 'emp.parquet') t 

but this return null.
Is this right approach to retrieve the contents from the stage file in snowpark?

I notice that you have a spelling issue in your code (you're using "paraquet" in place of "parquet"). I'm assuming that's not the issue, as it would error, but just want to make you aware of that. If the files in your stage are named "paraquet", they won't be read properly.
This is the standard way to read from a parquet in a stage. I am able to use your syntax almost exactly to read from parquet files from one of my own S3 stages.
I would try using session.sql and a select statement to see what is in your staged file:
select_statement = ("SELECT * FROM @data_stage/emp_data/file_path/emp.parquet")
df = session.sql(select_statement).collect_nowait().to_df()

df.show()

This won't parse the file the way that the parquet reader would, but it would help you troubleshoot why the parquet reader isn't working properly.

Hi @Bryan
I tried the same approach, but it retruning with empty data frame even though parquet file in the path

|$1|
|    |

even i tried with below approach
select t.$1 from @mystage (file_format => 'myformat', pattern => 'emp.parquet') t
but this return null

Can you provide an example of what the file looks like as it exists in the stage?
